# Rearrange the position of subtotal,shipment,tax in pdf invoice magento 2

Tags: magento2, invoice, pdf

I want to rearrange the position of  subtotal,shipment,tax in pdf invoice.
[image]

I want to move "tax" before grand total.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The sorting of the totals in the pdf is driven by the sort order assigned in the pdf.xml files. To for example change the sort order of tax create a new custom module and place into it the following etc/pdf.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Sales:etc/pdf_file.xsd">
    <totals>
        <total name="tax">
            <sort_order>650</sort_order>
        </total>
    </totals>
</config>
```

You also want to provide a sequence in your module so that it gets sorted after Magento_Tax.